# Rails capistrano deployment cannot find rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I am deploying my 1st Rails app using capistrano, unicorn, rbenv, nginx, linode, ubuntu 12.04. When I run

> bin/cap deploy:cold

in my app root, I get the following error back:

```
  * 2012-10-31 01:19:36 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/releases/20121031001933 && bundle install --gemfile /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/releases/20121031001933/Gemfile --path /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
    [xxxxxxxxxxxxx] executing command
 ** [out :: xxxxxxxxxxxxx] Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: xxxxxxxxxxxxx] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
    command finished in 1046ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/releases/20121031001933; true"
    servers: ["xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
    [xxxxxxxxxxxxx] executing command
    command finished in 625ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/releases/20121031001933 && bundle install --gemfile /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/releases/20121031001933/Gemfile --path /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have run bundle install --path vendor/bundle on my development machine, and gem rake is installed both on dev machine and on linode vps. Why cant it find rake?

UPDATE:

I have tried adding path of my rake gem on linode to both my bashrc on linode and to :default_envoronment in deploy.rb file. Still getting the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify your path in capistrano receipe, for example:

```
default_environment["PATH"] = "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin/:/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin"
```

If you don't know how looks your path, connect to your server via ssh and run command

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: So, at first try to run "cap your_deploy_receipe_name bundle:install". After that, log in to server with user which capistrano uses, and try to run command which failed (it will be bundle install I suppose). Is it works? If not, you need to add directories to your $PATH.

Comment: Didn't know I can do that, thx! will check it out! just dont know what you mean by this 'your_deploy_recipe_name'? Can you be more specific? Is that deploy.rb file?

Comment: capistrano is quite powerful tool. Run "cap -T" to list all of commands. You are using "your_deploy_recipe_name" if you need multistage (Few instances of your app, for example test, staging, production).

Comment: ok, so I just run cap bundle install? btw, I checked with gem environment where my gems are on my vps, and rake is in there correctly...

Comment: I have run : cap bundle:install. it says this > Cannot detect current release path - make sure you have deployed at least once.

Comment: try to: 1.setup your shared directory, 2.cap deploy:update_code, 3. cap deploy

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano tries to run command `cd /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/releases/20121031001933 && bundle install --gemfile /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/releases/20121031001933/Gemfile --path /home/mr_deployer/apps/prjct_mngr/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test` on remote machine where you service is deployed to.

Looks like remote node doesn't have `rake` installed that `bundle` trying to use.

Maybe you should check that all necessary gems are installed on remote machine.

Comment: running gem list shows that rake is indeed there on remote machine. Did you mean checking like that or?

Answer (score 0):

This error is not indicating that rake is not installed on the machine you are deploying to. This error means that Bundler, when it tried to install your gems, was unable to find Rake version 0.9.2.2 in the sources listed in your Gemfile. Does your Gemfile contain a line like `source "http://rubygems.org"`?

Comment: yes it does. but I dont have rake in gem file... btw, do I have to cap deploy:setup before cap deploy:cold each time I change my Gemfile?